# How to Html5 video pause after close popup video?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is modal show function

```
var _ouibounce = ouibounce(document.getElementById('popup-modal'), {
        aggressive: false,
        timer: 0,
        cookieExpire:1,
        delay:100,
        callback: function() { $('#popup-modal').show(); }
    });
```

This is my modal close function

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (e.target.className == 'underlay'){
        $('#popup-modal').hide();
    }

    $('#popup-modal .modal-footer').on('click', function() {
        $('#popup-modal').pause();      
    });
});
```

How to pause video after close popup video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery this should work:

```
$("#html_video_id").get(0).pause();
```

or plain:

```
document.getElementById('html_video_id').pause();
```